# Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных

Tags: грамматика

Если определение (обычно обособленное) стоит после счетного оборота, то чаще оно ставится в форме именительного падежа множественного числа, например: Направо от двери были два окна, завешенные платками (Л. Толстой); Последние два письма, писанные карандашом, меня испугали (Чехов); ...Два огромных **осмоленных** корыта, привалившиеся друг на друга... торчащие у самого выхода в открытую воду (Федин);

Почему тогда выделенное слово стоит в род.падеже? 
Предложение взято из справочника "Литературное редактирование текста" .Розенталь.Д.Э.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ПРАВИЛО**

**Форма определения**  в количественно-именных словосочетаниях с числительными **два, три, четыре** зависит  **от рода** имени существительного:
три высокие пальмы, две большие ложки – И. п. прилагательных для сущ. ж. р.: 
два высоких дерева, три больших ведра – Р. п. прилагательных для сущ. м.р. и ср.р.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**1) Основной формой**  для прилагательных является Р.п.:  два больших дерева.

2) Форма  И.п. (три высокие пальмы, две маленькие девочки) **является исключительной** и применяется в том случае, когда для существительного женского рода с точностью до ударения совпадают формы И.п. мн.числа  и Р.п. ед. числа: дЕвочки (мн.ч.) – нет дЕвочки (ед.ч.) В этом случае  сочетание    «две маленьких девочки» воспринимается на слух как нежелательное, лучше звучит  «две маленькие девочки». **Это известный в языке принцип сочетаемости рядом расположенных слов.**

3) **В осложненных конструкциях** на выбор формы сущ. оказывают влияние **другие факторы**: обособленные обороты, определение или сказуемое в препозиции к числовому сочетанию и т.д. Но в каждом случае использование И.п. (а не основного Р.п.) связано с желанием **обеспечить хорошую сочетаемость на слух, например:**

а) с числительными 2, 3, 4 естественнее сочетается **Р.п**.(два огромных осмоленных корыта), для двух определений этот фактор оказался решающим.

б) **обособленные** прилагательные чаще сочетаются со сказуемым в **И.п.**(последние два письма, писанные карандашом, меня испугали) , сказуемое в препозиции также задает **И.п.** (...были два окна, завешенные платками).

Comment: Это я знаю. Мне сбило с толку то, что в правиле говорится о им.пад., а приводится пример с род.пад.